# how to input out of html labels in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, user-interface, web, input, contenteditable

Using chrome, after adding a span label to a part of the content in a contenteditable div, if I put input cursor after the labeled part, (*by clicking and typing something*), the new chars are always appended inside the span label.

like

`<-span->[A](INPUT CURSOR HERE)<-/span->`

I want to set the cursor out of the span label.

`<-span->[A]<-/span->(INPUT CURSOR HERE)`

Here's my code below

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var html = $('div').text();
  $('div').html(html.replace(/\[A\]/g, '<span>[A]</span>'));
});
```

```css
span {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div contenteditable=true>wwww[A]ooo</div>
  <button>color</button>
  <br>1, click the button to make '[A]' in div highlight by adding the span labels.<br> 2, click the div, set the input cursor just after '[A]'. type something.<br> 3, if you are using chrome, the new chars must be highlight. because the cursor is in
  the span labels. and if you are using firefox, it may be highlight or normal by chance. how can i move the cursor out of the span labels to input normal chars follow the span [A]?
</body>

</html>
```

how to do it?

Comment: Do not use an external code reference. Just put a minimal example in your question.

Comment: look into `http://api.jquery.com/before/` and `http://api.jquery.com/after/`